# How can I see my Gmail contacts?

Tags: gmail, contacts

Some how I removed my Contacts from the left side of Gmail. I know I still have them but I cannot find out how to list them as all instruction state "Click on Contacts on the left side", but as I say, I have removed this access somehow.

How can I restore this facility?

Comment: Is there a [+] sign next to the "Mail" label under the Google logo?

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Please add this to your answer for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the gmail logo (left corner under Google) and the option gmail, contacts and tasks will come up. Obviously, click contacts.

Its a weird place to have put it... But hope this helped!

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on how you get your Contacts back into Gmail, but until then, go to https://www.google.com/contacts and you should see them there.

**Update 5/11/11:**

If there is a [+] icon next to "Mail" in the upper-left corner, click it, and it will expand to reveal "Contacts" and "Tasks".

Answer (score 0):

Check your [Better Gmail 2](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/better-gmail-2/) Firefox extension settings, un-check:

`Relocate contacts and tasks to top navigation`

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: My guess is that "better gmail" is either a Chrome or Firefox extension. Not everyone has it installed by default, but if you do have it installed, some settings can do very funny things. (OTH, it _is_ a nice extension. I've used it a lot in the past.)